# Linq: Order by date and Find the first element

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to query a datatable where i select list of rows based on some data and order the rows  by date and get the row with latest date. This is what I did

```
var propertyValueId = _dbSis.Set<PropertyValue>()
                            .Where(m => m.PropertyInstanceId == id)
                            .OrderBy(z => z.TimeStamp);
var pvalueId = propertyValueId.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
```

but I get error on `propertyValueId.ElementAtOrDetault(0);`

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Sorama.DataModel.SIS.Configuration.PropertyValue ElementAtOrDefault[PropertyValue](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Sorama.DataModel.SIS.Configuration.PropertyValue], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How can I achieve what I just expected, and how can i solve the error?

Comment: `DataTable` is not `LINQ to Entities`, is it?

Comment: Did you try `FirstOrDefault()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems strange that [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) does not work.

```
var pvalueId = propertyValueId.FirstOrDefault();
```

Should that not be supported:

```
var pvalueId = propertyValueId.Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Or, if for some bizarre reason your L2EF provider cannot handle `FirstOrDefault`, `Take`, or `SingleOrDefault`, you can brute force it:

```
PropertyValue pvalueId = null;
foreach (var pv in propertyValueId)
{
    pvalueId = pv;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this error occurs is that **Linq to Entities** does not support lot of **Linq to Objects** methods. It is because Linq to Entities converts your query to expression tree that then will be executed on SQL.  
Full list of supported and unsupported methods you can find [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx).

And as **@Gusdor** mentioned: The unrecognized method in the expression (which your lambdas are resolving to) is being treated as a Stored Procedure which in turn does not exist. Easy way to check what will happen is to look at the parameter list for the LINQ method.

So to fix your problem you should use allowed method, like `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var pvalueId = propertyValueId.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: To add some detail, the unrecognized method in the expression (which your lambdas are resolving to) is being treated as a Stored Procedure which in turn does not exist. Easy way to check what will happen is to look at the parameter list for the LINQ method. If it expects Expression<T> you need to watch your step.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try :

```
var propertyValueId = _dbSis.Set<PropertyValue()
                            .Where(m=>m.PropertyInstanceId==id)
                            .OrderBy(z=>z.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault();
```